# How to display modified body after Outlook ItemLoad

Tags: email, outlook, vsto, c2call

I have code to parse emails and add "tel:" links to phone numbers, but the modified email body doesn't get shown in the Outlook Reading Pane until the user manually reloads it (view another email, come back to this one).

I've tried a few hacks like `Inspector.Display`, and `ActiveExplorer.ClearSelection ActiveExplorer.AddToSelection`, but I can't get consistent results (Display will open new Inspectors for some users, very undesirable).

I was also going to investigate hooking the event sooner. Somehow accessing the email body before Outlook renders it, to avoid the need to refresh. I'm very new to VSTO, so I don't know what event would have access to the MailItem but happen after a user selects it and before it is rendered. I have thought about only processing new mail, but that doesn't help when I roll out this addin, only going forward.

Here is my current ItemLoad sub:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(Item As Object)
    Dim myObj As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim ob As Object
    ob = GetCurrentItem()
    If TypeOf ob Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        myObj = ob
        Dim oldbody As String = myObj.Body
        If myObj.HTMLBody.Length > 0 Then
            myObj.HTMLBody = RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(myObj.HTMLBody, "(?<!tel:)(?<![2-9\.])(?<!\>\ )[+]?(1-)?(1)?[\(]?(?<p1>\d{3})[\)]?[\.\- ]?(?<p2>\d{3})[\.\- ]?(?<p3>\d{4})(?=[^\d])", "<a href=""tel:${p1}${p2}${p3}""> ${p1}-${p2}-${p3}</a>")
        Else
            myObj.Body = RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(myObj.Body, "(?<!tel:)(?<![2-9\.])[+]?(1-)?(1)?[\(]?(?<p1>\d{3})[\)]?[\.\- ]?(?<p2>\d{3})[\.\- ]?(?<p3>\d{4})(?=[^\d])", "tel:${p1}.${p2}.${p3}")
        End If
        myObj.Save()
        refreshCurrentMessage()
    End If
End Sub
```

`GetCurrentItem()` just returns either `objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)` or `objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem` based on `TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)`

Answer (score 0):

Outlook doesn't reflect changes made through the OOM immediately. You need to switch to another folder/email to get the item refreshed because there is no way to update the item on the fly.

You can use the [CurrentFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866719(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Explorer class which allows to set a Folder object that represents the current folder displayed in the explorer. Thus, the view will be switched to another folder. Then you can set the CurrentFolder folder to initial folder.

Also I'd suggest releasing all underlying COM objects instantly. Use *System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject* to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I wish there was a better answer than loading other emails, since this could create a loop if I hook the ItemLoad event, and it seems really inefficient. There is a product called teletrigger that is somehow able to modify only what is displayed, without changing the email body. I have no clue how to do that though.